# Do advaita vedanta believe in hell as a real place?

Tags: advaita

Do advaita vedanta believes in hell as a place where sin full people will be suffer with pain.

Or do they believe that hell is a state of mind.

Comment: Naraka does exist. Although 1. It is not eternal 2. It is not meant to be bad and there are nice pockets in it. It also has some positive attributes like a beautiful view.

Comment: Modern Advaita...particularly as understood in the West, the answer would be no. The "me" is an illusion and never really existed. There is only Brahman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it appears from Shankara bhAshyas, that he considered hell to be a real place (not ultimately real, but empirically real).

[Brahmasutra bhAshya 3.1.13](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38089.htm)

> The latter (those who do not perform sacrifices or holy acts) **descend to Samyamana, the abode of Yama, suffer there the torments of Yama corresponding to their evil deeds, and then again re-ascend to this world.** Such is their ascent and descent; as we maintain on the ground of such a course being declared by scripture. For a scriptural passage embodying Yama's own words declares that **those who die without having offered sacrifices fall into Yama's power.'**

[Brahmasutra bhAshya 3.1.14](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38090.htm)

> Moreover, authorities like Manu, Vyâsa, &c., declare that **in the city Samyamana evil works are requited under Yama's rule;** cp. the legend of Nâkiketa and others.

[Brahmasutra bhAshya 3.1.15](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38091.htm)

> Moreover, the **purâna-writers record that there are seven hells, Raurava, &c., by name, which serve as abodes of enjoyment of the fruits of evil deeds.** As those who do not sacrifice, &c. go there, how should they reach the moon?--

[Brahmasutra bhAshya 3.1.16](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38092.htm)

> There is no contradiction, as **the same Yama is admitted to act as chief ruler in those seven hells.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Does he describe tortures of hell.